# What does 捜す refer to here?

Tags: meaning

> 沢庵 ｛たくあん｝ 「花御堂にかざる花を、一人で摘むのはたいへんだ、わしも手伝おうよ」
>   お通 ｛つう｝ 「そんな、裸のままで、見ッともない」
>   沢庵 「人間は元来、裸のものさ、かまわん」
>   お通 「いやですよ、尾いて来ては！」
>
> お通｛つう｝は逃げるように、寺の裏へ駈けて行った。やがて負い籠を背にかけ、鎌を持って、こっそり裏門からぬけてゆくと、沢庵｛たくあん｝は、**どこから捜してきたのか**、ふとんでも包むような大きな風呂敷を体に巻いて、後から歩いてきた。

宮本武蔵（1935年–1939年、朝日新聞連載、吉川英治）

Does it refer to Takuan finding お通 (who was trying to sneak out) or the ふとんでも包むような大きな風呂敷?

Reference: http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/001562/files/52396_49781.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My immediate assumption as I read it was that どこから捜してきたのか referred to the odd 風呂敷 he had wrapped around him, giving a "where the heck did he find that?" impression.